# Can you freeze egg noodle pasta?

Tags: freezing, pasta, food-preservation

I recently made fresh egg noodle pasta. I made too much! Can I freeze it? I have tried freezing other kinds of pasta but am skeptical of freezing egg noodle pasta. What should I do?

Comment: But when you freeze it for too long it may get freeze burns and that's bad.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can freeze it.  Per [Eat By Date](http://www.eatbydate.com/grains/pasta-shelf-life-expiration-date/), it should last 6-8 months when frozen.

The eggs don't really change the ability to freeze it.  For example, you can also freeze raw cookie dough containing eggs.

Comment: You might want to divide whatever is leftover into individual portions prior to freezing so that you don't have to thaw the whole thing unless you want to.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to add one more point. Yes, you can freeze homemade egg pasta and it does very well. Furthermore, you can add the still frozen pasta to boiling water to cook it. It does so beautifully that way that there is no discernible difference between "just made" pasta and pasta that has been frozen. No need to defrost, just add the frozen pasta to the boiling water.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you freeze uncooked noodles because cooked noodles are nasty when you try to thaw and cook again.  You can also freeze balls of the dough and then take it out and thaw about an hour before using it to make "fresh" noodles as needed!

Answer (score 0):

I cut them as thin as I can. I use a straight edge.

Cut them as narrow as you want. Then lay the pasta out on a large cutting board. Use big floor fan that turns back and forth. In about an hour, vacuum seal them.

I just dump them in boiling broth frozen, they fall right apart in about ten minutes.